# Ubuntu 19.10 Drops Into Grub2 Command Line After update-grub On ZFS Rootfs

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.10, zfs

NOTE: Yes, I know I should have taken a snapshot of bpool. This would have solved this whole problem, but I forgot to do this.

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 as a clean install with ZFS on a whole hard drive.

I a few changes to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=off splash"
```

I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install
```

Then I rebooted.

At this point, I was dropped into the grub command line. There were no menu entries, and my system is unbootable.

I'd really not like to re-install as I had already customized my system and moved lots of personal data onto it.

I ran an Ubuntu rescue disk to fix this. I was able to mount my `rpool` and `bpool` partitions and `chroot` into them, but `update-grub` and `grub-install` did not find my current Ubuntu root and did not populate `grub.cfg`.

I had read that `os-prober` was a problem:

https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/issues/193

```
sudo os-prober
```

Yields this:

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on osprober-linux-sdb5
failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed.
```

Also, `grub-probe` fails. Running:

```
sudo grub-probe /
```

Yields:

```
grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
```

So this might explain why grub is not working. Here's the version:

```
grub-probe (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu12.1
```

Any ideas on how to make this system bootable again besides re-installing?

Comment: I have exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before you `chroot`,

you need do this (after you have booted from your rescue disk and got things mounted):

- `mv $target_root/dev $target_root/dev.save && mkdir $target_root/dev`
- `mount --bind /dev $target_root/dev`
  (you might need to do the same for your `/sys`)

Only THEN you can chroot to `$target_root/` and expect things to work. After you exit from chroot, don't forget to `umount $target_root/dev && rmdir $target_root/dev && mv $target_root/dev.save $target_root/dev` (and do the same for `/sys` if you used that). Or else you won't be able to boot cause your `/dev` won't be in place.

2. But actually

you must be able to install GRUB without all that chroot stuff.
Just check `/etc/fstab` and learn what your partitions are. Get your root (/) device from there.

Most likely you'll find UUIDs instead of /dev/sd* device names. No problem!! Get device name from `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` where you find your UUIDs and devices they are linked to.

Learn where your `/boot/grub` is located -- most likely it's on your root, so `ls /boot/grub` is enough to make sure.

The standard `grub-install` command WON'T FIND ANYTHING, you need to supply your target installation (root) device to it:

`grub-install /dev/sda` (instead of `/dev/sda` supply your root device you found from `/etc/fstab`).

3. Oh, and you might want to [check how to invoke](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Invoking-grub_002dprobe.html) `grub-probe` to get sensible answer from it:

`grub-probe --target=disk /` (or any other --target)

Comment: Here's my grub. Where's /? ```UUID=49C3-39DC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
/boot/efi/grub /boot/grub none defaults,bind 0 0
UUID=4dba7055-7ecd-4ed7-b714-b55f1ff80bb2 none swap discard 0 0
```

Comment: Your /etc/fstab you mean? Evidently, that is your /etc/fstab. But I mean the /etc/fstab of your installation root. Use `df -h` command to see what IS mounted and WHERE it is mounted. Especially, where is your installed root mounted by the rescue disk.

Comment: Yes because ZFS is special in that it does not require the mount points to be in /etc/fstab. So looking if /etc/fstab is not appropriate for ZFS. Instead, you should mount the filesystem: zpool import -R /mnt rpool, I think.

Comment: Ah, you're right of course. Just in my system I use `legacy` mountpoints and fstab. Makes things SO much easier in cases like yours!!.. Well use `zpool status` to check the rpool system device. Then you'll see which system device to install your grub to. Then mount your /boot/efi & /boot/efi/grub as you showed above. Then you'll be able to use the command `grub-install` $your_root_device`.

Comment: In my grub.cfg I have this `menuentry 'Ubuntu Xenial' {
        insmod gzio
        insmod zfs
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  cd397a8f11725bf3
        linux   /ROOT/ubuntu-root/@/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic root=ZFS=mypool/ROOT/u
buntu-root spl.spl_hostid=0x7e9d02ec ro boot=zfs net.ifname=0 biosdevname=0 nouveau.black
list=1
        initrd /ROOT/ubuntu-root/@/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
}` But I don't use EFI partition,  so all the needed modules are zfs, gzio.